# TFS mapping vs Subversion

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I am new to TFS, I have been mainly using Subversion.  I am confused with the "mapping" concept.  It looks like TFS maps a local folder to a source controlled folder.  So every local change I make "automatically" gets added to source control???

I only ask b/c I am got the latest version of a project that was built using Visual Studio 2005, and I have Visual Studio 2010.  So of course I have to convert it on my "local" folder, but the source folder already "sees" that I have made that change.  I tried to undo pending changes, but the solution in source control still shows the VS2010 icon.  Hopefully I did not change the solution for everyone else to VS2010 when I didn't even commit any changes.

Is there a way to back out any changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No problem yeah getting used to TFS from VSS, Subversion or any other tool can be tricky.

Mapping allows you to, as you guessed, map a sourced folder to a local folder.

> "So every local change I make
>   "automatically" gets added to source
>   control???"

It doesn't work quite like that.  TFS will only control files that you have explicitly added to source control.  So, for instance, if you add 50 files inside of a folder you have mapped in TFS, you will not have those automatically added in Source control.  You can though add them in if you want.

There are some exceptions to this though but even when TFS picks up a file it will ask you before adding it to source control (example being websites- it will detect a new file and ask if you want to add to source control).

How that icon shows is based on your locally installed tools and how you associate the sln to your VS version.  Don't worry about that icon.  If you didn't checkin an upgraded version of the sln by going through the upgrade wizard then checking that into TFS you don't have a problem here.

Comment: Yeah I know it can be stressful. One of our QA members accidentally checked out an entire Team Project once when I first started with the tool. Needless to say I quickly learned how permissions worked lol :) This is a great place to get help with these types of questions too- community is really good at lending a hand. Also make sure to mark one of the answers you got as correct so that it can help others in the future find appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

A mapping simply determines what local folder corresponds to a server folder.

With TFS, nothing automatically gets added to source control.  If you want to add a file to source control you still need to pend a change for the file.  That said, when you're using Visual Studio, changes are pended automatically - when you add a file, it will be pended for addition to the server, when you open a file and start editing, it will be pended for edit, etc.  This differs from Subversion in that you notify when you make changes instead of at commit time.

Once a file has had a change pended, this change still only exists locally.  You can view the changes that you have pended in the Pending Changes view, available under View > Pending Changes.  When you want to commit to the server, you can select Check In from this view.

If you wanted to check to see if something had been checked in, you can open up the Source Control Explorer, navigate to that file, right-click and select View History.  You can retrieve previous changes this way, by selecting a version in history and selecting "Get This Version".  If you wanted to roll back, you could then check this version back in, making it the latest version.